# Cancelling a Task results in ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, task

In my Xamarin iOS app I have a method that uploads user profile data and profile image to the server. It looks like this:

```cs
public async Task UploadProfileAndImage (ProfileInputModel profile, Image image, Action<bool, string> completion)
{
    if (AreProfileAndImageBeingUploaded ()) {
        CancelProfileAndImageUpload ();
    }

    if (completion != null) {
        _uploadCallbacks.Add (completion);
    }
    _uploadCancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource ();

    var tasks = new List<Task<ApiResponse>> ();

    Task<ApiResponse> profileTask = null;
    if (profile != null) {
        profileTask = ProfileApi.UpdateProfile (profile, _uploadCancellationSource.Token);
        tasks.Add (profileTask);
    }

    Task<ApiResponse> imageTask = null;
    if (image.ImageBytes != null) {
        imageTask = ProfileApi.SetProfilePicture (image, _uploadCancellationSource.Token);
        tasks.Add (imageTask);
    }

    var both = Task.WhenAll (tasks.ToArray ());

    try {

        var responses = await both;
        var success = true;
        foreach (ApiResponse a in responses) {
            if (!a.IsSuccessful) {
                success = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        foreach (Action<bool, string> callback in _uploadCallbacks) {
            if (success) {
                callback (true, null);
            } else {
                callback (false, "Error occurred");
            }
        }
    } catch (OperationCanceledException) {
        foreach (Action<bool, string> callback in _uploadCallbacks) {
            callback (false, "Operation cancelled");
        }    
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Debug.WriteLine (ex);
    } finally {
        _uploadCancellationSource.Dispose ();
        _uploadCancellationSource = null;
        _uploadCallbacks.Clear ();
    }
}

public void CancelProfileAndImageUpload ()
{
    if (_uploadCancellationSource != null) {
        _uploadCancellationSource.Cancel ();
    }
}

public async Task<ApiResponse> UpdateProfile(ProfileInputModel profile, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using (var client = CreateHttpClient())
    {
        var body = new JsonContent(profile);
        var response = await client.PutAsync ("profile", body, cancellationToken);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            return HandleFault<bool>(response);
        }

        return ApiResponse.Success();
    }
}

public async Task<ApiResponse> SetProfilePicture (Image picture, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using (var client = CreateHttpClient ())
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream (picture.ImageBytes);
        var content = new StreamContent (memoryStream);
        content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue (picture.MediaType);

        var response = await client.PostAsync ("profile/image", content, cancellationToken);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            return HandleFault<bool>(response);
        }

        return ApiResponse.Success();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I call `UploadProfileAndImage` while the previous upload is still running, `CancelProfileAndImageUpload` gets called resulting in an exception being thrown.

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: The object was used after being disposed.
```

The object that was used is `System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream` and the exception is thrown in `System.Net.WebConnection.EndWrite`.

Has anyone experienced anything like the above and knows what I'm doing wrong?

---

**Update**

Here is a sample Xamarin project:

[Download from Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By724U00O2KAVklBVG11NXNTVG8/view?usp=sharing)

The exception is thrown when clicking fast multiple times on the button displayed by the app. The example reuses the code posted in this question.

And here is a stack trace of the exception:

```
    2015-06-25 00:35:11.075 Example[2713:111447] System.ObjectDisposedException: The object was used after being disposed.
  at System.Net.WebConnection.EndWrite (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, Boolean throwOnError, IAsyncResult result) [0x0002c] in //Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.10.1.64/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:1071 
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.WriteAsyncCB (IAsyncResult r) [0x00013] in //Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.10.1.64/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnectionStream.cs:458 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:477 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x002f4] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:344 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:372 
  at Shared.CookieAwareMessageHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00115] in /Users/mku/Documents/Private projects/Xamarin/Example/Shared/CookeAwareMessageHandler.cs:30 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:580 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000a9] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:274 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:372 
  at Shared.ProfileApi+<SetProfilePicture>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000df] in /Users/mku/Documents/Private projects/Xamarin/Example/Shared/ProfileApi.cs:23 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[Shared.ApiResponse[]].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:372 
  at Shared.ProfileDownloader+<UploadProfileAndImage>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x0013e] in /Users/mku/Documents/Private projects/Xamarin/Example/Shared/ProfileDownloader.cs:57 
System.ObjectDisposedException: The object was used after being disposed.
  at System.Net.WebConnection.EndWrite (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, Boolean throwOnError, IAsyncResult result) [0x0002c] in //Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.10.1.64/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:1071 
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.WriteAsyncCB (IAsyncResult r) [0x00013] in //Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.10.1.64/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnectionStream.cs:458 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:477 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x002f4] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:344 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:372 
  at Shared.CookieAwareMessageHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00115] in /Users/mku/Documents/Private projects/Xamarin/Example/Shared/CookeAwareMessageHandler.cs:30 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:580 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000a9] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:274 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:372 
  at Shared.ProfileApi+<SetProfilePicture>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000df] in /Users/mku/Documents/Private projects/Xamarin/Example/Shared/ProfileApi.cs:23 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[Shared.ApiResponse[]].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1503/e6ebd18b/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:372 
  at Shared.ProfileDownloader+<UploadProfileAndImage>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x0013e] in /Users/mku/Documents/Private projects/Xamarin/Example/Shared/ProfileDownloader.cs:57
```

Comment: Post the code for `CancelProfileAndImageUpload`

Comment: I've added it at the bottom of the code sample

Comment: So it fails in one of the ProfileApi methods and it would be useful to show them here. It's important how you handle the cancellation token in those.

Comment: @MarcinKuptel: Can you post a minimal, reproducible example that others can run?

Comment: @StephenCleary: Sure thing. I don't have one ready at the moment though, so it will be a little later today.

Comment: It would be also helpful to include the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Updated the question with an example and a stack trace.